# Is there a terminal app for Mac OS X that makes URLs clickable?

Tags: macos, terminal, url

I would like to find a terminal app for Mac OS X that automatically turns any URLs in the text into clickable links. I seem to recall that one of the default ones in the Gnome desktop for Linux did that, and I miss it.

Comment: Sorry, we don't deal with software recommendations questions here; they tend to go out of date quickly. In the future, please use softwarerecs.stackexchange.com for such questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default terminal has clickable links, CMD+double click will open the link in your default browser.

In iterm2 CMD+click works.